# IBM Watson Assistant: Transfer from Chat to Representative and include chat history

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am currently creating a standard chatbot with IBM Watson Assistant. The bot asks several questions and gathers information. At a specific point in time, the user will be asked if he wants to transfer the information entered to a representative. If the user says "yes" it would be great if Watson Assistent then can transfer the chatlog in an e-mail to a employee of our firm.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The conversation with Watson Assistant is driven by an application. That app would need to react to the detected intent or context variable that signals "transfer to representative".

Essential information for that chat could either be carried by a context variable or [stored in a database](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html#build-a-database-driven-slackbot). That data could then be made available to the representative. Another option would be for the app to [retrieve the chat log using the API / SDK](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/curl.html?curl#logs-api). The app knows about the conversation_id and could use it to look up the related log entries. In addition, it could [filter out the input text and responses](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/filter-reference.html#filter-query-reference).

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. Sounds complicated. Unfortunately I have barely no programming skills and do all the work the IBM watson bot tool.

Comment: You mean the workspace editor? Take a look at the suggested solution architecture https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/index.html#about There are some SDKs that take away most of the programming, but...